# Assembly language prints character twice with function call but not when executed directly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to make my own bootloader written in 16 bit assembly. I am able to print text to a screen using `int 10h, AH = 0Eh`.

If I run

```
MOV AL, 65
MOV AH, 0Eh 
int 10h
HLT
```

I am successfully able to print `A` to the screen.

However, if I am to do

```
MOV AL, 65
CALL printc

HLT

printc:
  MOV AH, 0Eh 
  int 10h 
  RET
```

I end up getting `AA` displayed on the screen instead.

Why is this and how would I fix it?

Here is my full code:

```
BITS 16
ORG 0x7C00

MOV DS, AX
MOV SI, 0x7C00


MOV AL, 65
CALL printc

HLT

printc:
  MOV AH, 0Eh 
  int 10h 
  RET 

times 510-($-$$) db 0x90
dw 0xAA55
```

Comment: Try making an endless loop around the `HLT`. It's not a complete halt, interrupts will wake up the cpu from that state.

Comment: Thanks @Jester That seems to have worked. I would have thought HLT halted the system and froze it in that state. If you add this as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote the instruction set reference:

> HLT Stops instruction execution and places the processor in a HALT state. An enabled interrupt (including NMI and
>   SMI), a debug exception, the BINIT# signal, the INIT# signal, or the RESET# signal will resume execution.

As you can see, an interrupt will resume execution and at least the timer interrupt is usually running, along with other possible sources such as key presses.

Thus, you should add a loop around the `HLT` to make it go back to sleep.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. So if I am to disable interrupts, `HLT` should act as `JMP $` then?

Comment: Except for the other possible wakeup events, yes.

Comment: @iProgram: IIRC, Michael Petch said you usually don't need a loop if you disable interrupts.  Most PCs don't generate NMIs (non-maskable interrupts).